# ActiveRecord Multi Level Single Table Inheritance Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord

I am trying to use Single Table Inheritance to query for all records within a class hierarchy from a class that is not the base class for the single table inheritance.  For example, given the following class heirarchy.

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base; end

class Dog < Animal; end

class Mutt < Dog; end

class PureBred < Dog; end
```

I want to be able to query for all of the dogs

```
dogs = Dog.all
```

and dogs be a list of instances of Mutt and PureBred.

Can this be done?  I tried a proof of concept by setting the default_scope in the Dog class to

```
default_scope { where(:type => ['Mutt', 'PureBred']) }
```

but ActiveRecord is still appending the more restrictive condition of WHERE type IN ('Dog')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; you're running up against a technical limitation of Rails' implementation of STI.

You'll have to query the base class:

```
Animal.where(type: %w(Dog Mutt PureBred))
```